# completion for .bash_history

Tags: company-mode, bash, ivy, term

I am considering implementing an ivy-powered bash_history greper for term-mode, but before I do I wanted to know if this has already been done, by some fancy company-bashhistory package or whatever. Something like a company-style dropdown for C-r in a terminal. Is this available already?

Comment: Alright, turns out the Ivy API makes this super easy to do. Will post when I have time (and submit to Melpa if anyone is interested)

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in the comment, this was actually a piece of cake using ivy-read. It's now available on https://github.com/tautologyclub/counsel-term-history